# Cancel parent custom dialog click on textview

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have custom alert dialog.When i am click the text view in custom dialog this will be closed and another custom dialog opened.But not closed this custom dialog.

```
Alert.Builder alertViewTaskDescription = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        getActivity());
LayoutInflater inflaterViewTaskDescription = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
        .getSystemService(getActivity().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
viewTaskWithDescription = (View) inflaterViewTaskDescription
        .inflate(R.layout.viewtaskwithdescriptionlayout, null,
                false);

TextView textviewTask = (TextView) viewTaskWithDescription
        .findViewById(R.id.taskidDaytoDayView);
TextView textviewDescription = (TextView) viewTaskWithDescription
        .findViewById(R.id.descriptionidDaytoDayView);
textviewTask.setText(taskName);

textviewDescription.setText("ADD DESCRIPTION");
alertViewTaskDescription.setView(viewTaskWithDescription);
alertDialog = alertViewTaskDescription.create();
textviewDescription.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        alertDialog.cancel();
        AlertDialog.Builder alertEditTaskDescription = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflaterEditTaskDescription = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(
                        getActivity().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View viewEditTaskDescription = (View) inflaterEditTaskDescription
                .inflate(R.layout.edittaskwithdescriptionlayout,
                        null, false);
        final EditText edittextTask = (EditText) viewEditTaskDescription
                .findViewById(R.id.taskidDaytoDayEdit);
        final EditText edittextDescription = (EditText) viewEditTaskDescription
                .findViewById(R.id.descriptionidDaytoDayEdit);
        edittextTask.setText(taskName);
        edittextDescription.setText(taskDescription);
        edittextTask.setSelection(edittextTask.getText()
                .length());
        edittextDescription
                .setSelection(edittextDescription.getText()
                        .length());
        alertEditTaskDescription
                .setView(viewEditTaskDescription);
        alertEditTaskDescription.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(
                        DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                }
            });

        alertViewTaskDescription.create().show();
    }});
```

Comment: So, alertDialog.cancel() get executed, but alertDialog still stays on the screen?

Comment: yes how to solve this problem sandrstar

Comment: Is new dialog shown above existing one?

Comment: yes when i click the textviewDescription the new alert open but this old one not invisible.

Comment: at a time two view is on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked the following code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private AlertDialog mDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertViewTaskDescription = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflaterViewTaskDescription = (LayoutInflater) this
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final ViewGroup viewTaskWithDescription = (ViewGroup) inflaterViewTaskDescription
                .inflate(R.layout.viewtaskwithdescriptionlayout, null, false);

        TextView textviewTask = (TextView) viewTaskWithDescription
                .findViewById(R.id.taskidDaytoDayView);
        TextView textviewDescription = (TextView) viewTaskWithDescription
                .findViewById(R.id.descriptionidDaytoDayView);
        textviewTask.setText("Task Name");

        textviewDescription.setText("ADD DESCRIPTION");
        alertViewTaskDescription.setView(viewTaskWithDescription);

        textviewDescription.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getDialog().cancel();
                createSecondDialog();
            }});

        mDialog = alertViewTaskDescription.create();
        mDialog.show();
    }


    public AlertDialog getDialog() {
        return mDialog;
    }

    private void createSecondDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertEditTaskDescription = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);

        LayoutInflater inflaterEditTaskDescription = (LayoutInflater) MyActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View viewEditTaskDescription = (View) inflaterEditTaskDescription
                .inflate(R.layout.edittaskwithdescriptionlayout,
                        null, false);
        final EditText edittextTask = (EditText) viewEditTaskDescription
                .findViewById(R.id.taskidDaytoDayEdit);
        final EditText edittextDescription = (EditText) viewEditTaskDescription
                .findViewById(R.id.descriptionidDaytoDayEdit);
        edittextTask.setText("Task name 1");
        edittextDescription.setText("Task description!");
        edittextTask.setSelection(edittextTask.getText()
                .length());
        edittextDescription
                .setSelection(edittextDescription.getText()
                        .length());
        alertEditTaskDescription
                .setView(viewEditTaskDescription);
        alertEditTaskDescription.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(
                            DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                    }
                });

        mDialog = alertEditTaskDescription.create();

        mDialog.show();
    }
}
```

And it worked fine. I believe, storing of the dialog in Activity resolved the issue. Please, also check the naming, because it looks like You're calling wrong dialog to show in `onClick(View v)` -> `alertViewTaskDescription.create().show();` (instead of `alertEditTaskDescription.create().show()`).

Comment: Have You tried it (it just needs to change this to getActivity())?

Comment: Thank you very much its working for me...but i have one doubt why we create one alert instance such that mdialog as globally.

Comment: Seems it might be needed to show only 1 alert at the time, so I suggest to track only that 'active' dialog. Also, You might need to consider usage of DialogFragment instead of AlertDialog as Google recommends (I'm sure that the design will be more clear with it).

Comment: Thanks sandrstar and i need one example for listview.if we using expandable listview which have collapse function but i need listview with collapse please help me...